# Is there an API that lets one sync an iOS app with its OSX counterpart via USB?

Tags: ios, objective-c, macos

I am developing an iOS app, which may need to sync a large amount of data with its OSX counterpart app, and for the use case in which the app would be used there may not be an internet connection available to connect either of the devices (iOS device & Mac).

Is there an official apple api that lets one sync data between an iOS app, and its OSX counterpart, without having to use the internet or iCloud ?

As far as I can tell, short of joining the MFI program, there isn't a way.

Comment: The MFI program is only if you want to develop hardware for iOS devices. An option could be to use bluetooth or an Ad-Hoc network to sync the data between the two apps.

Comment: I've considered bluetooth, but USB would really be the simplest option for the end user.

Comment: Well you could use iTunes file sharing as suggested by wisty. I don't think allow will allow you to use the standard USB cable for data communication.

Comment: No dragging and dropping files would be too much of a hassle - the data that needs to be transferred is between the two apps. Would be too complicated for the end user to do himself.

Comment: Then I guess you're just out of luck, what you want is something that with the current SDK is just not available.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you don't mind the user dragging some documents around, then you can create documents which can be accessed via iTunes: http://www.raywenderlich.com/1948/itunes-tutorial-for-ios-how-to-integrate-itunes-file-sharing-with-your-ios-app

Comment: I'm aware of that, but it would be too much of a hassle for the end user.

Answer (score 0):

What makes you think you need an Internet connection for WiFi?

If you are close enough for a USB cable, just create a WiFi network from the Mac (WiFi icon in the menu bar, "Create connection..."). Use bonjour to discover services, and then the apps can talk to each other.

Comment: That would be too complicated for the end user, which is why I would prefer to just use a USB cable.